# Как создать Python словарь из двух списков разной длины

Tags: python, массивы, list

Иметься массив с елементами:

```
key = ['cpu', 'freq', 'cache']
```

и массив с значениями:

```
data = ['i9 9900k', '5', '8', 'ryzen 5 1600', '3.1', '8']
```

Как получить словари формата:

```
{
            'cpu' : 'i9 9900k',
            'freq' : '5',
            'cache' : '8'
        },
{
            'cpu' : 'ryzen 5 1600',
            'freq' : '3.1',
            'cache' : '8'
        }
```

Comment: 2 вложенных цикла. Внешний по `data`, внутренний по `key`

Answer (score 2):

zip() Объединяет списки. но у Вас они разной длинны. если "заголовки" и данные будут всегда записаны в таком виде:

```
key = ['cpu', 'freq', 'cache']
data = ['i9 9900k', '5', '8', 'ryzen 5 1600', '3.1', '8']
```

то

```
res = []
for i in range(0,len(data),3):
    res.append(dict(zip(key, data[i:i+3])))
print(res)
# список словарей [{'cpu': 'i9 9900k', 'freq': '5', 'cache': '8'}, {'cpu': 'ryzen 5 1600', 'freq': '3.1', 'cache': '8'}]
```

или

```
res = [dict(zip(key, data[i:i+3])) for i in range(0,len(data),3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть простое решение, использующее особенность `zip`. `zip` останавливается как только закончился самый короткий список. В нашем случае это будет список `key`. Список `data` завернут в вызов `iter`. Благодаря этому в каждом последующем вызове `zip` считывается следующий фрагмент из `data`. Выход из цикла происходит когда `zip` перестал возвращать данные - это значит что итератор дошел до конца списка `data`:

```
def dicts(key, data):
    it = iter(data)
    while True:
        d = dict(zip(key, it)) 
        if d:
            yield d
        else:
            break

key = ['cpu', 'freq', 'cache']
data = ['i9 9900k', '5', '8', 'ryzen 5 1600', '3.1', '8']
print(*dicts(key, data), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ python dicts.py
> {'cpu': 'i9 9900k', 'freq': '5', 'cache': '8'}
> {'cpu': 'ryzen 5 1600', 'freq': '3.1', 'cache': '8'}
> ```

**P.S.** в коде выше `zip(key, it)` будет работать как надо, а если поменять местами аргументы, `zip(it, key)` будет терять данные. Подробности тут: [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).